# Can anyone help me, how do I give a line break in JS?

Tags: javascript

```js
export const Pelayanan = [
  {
    id: 1,
    image: Service1,
    star1: "fa-solid fa-star",
    star2: "fa-solid fa-star",
    star3: "fa-solid fa-star",
    star4: "fa-solid fa-star",
    star5: "fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke",
    title: "p",
    price: "a",
    buy: "Pesan Sekarang",
    NamaFitur: "Fitur Paket Small",
    Fitur: "jda",
    delay: "300",
  },
]
```

How do you give a line break in JS?

Comment: If your javascript is used to display html, you can add `<br />`

Comment: What do you mean by line break?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) It's not clear what you're asking here. If you mean, how do you put a line break in a **string**, see [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450778/the-correct-syntax-for-entering-a-line-break-in-a-javascript-string). Otherwise, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77136098/edit) the question to provide more context and details.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692039/how-to-use-n-in-a-javascript-string/48692063#48692063) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

To add a line break to a Javascript string, include the characters "\n" inside the quotation marks.